# How to filter rows in one table with values from joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
products
| id |
------
|  1 |
|  2 |

attributes
| product_id |           value |
--------------------------------
|          1 | Needed value #1 |
|          1 | Needed value #2 |
|          2 | Needed value #1 |
```

I need to select a product that has both `Needed value #1` and `Needed value #2`. Can't get it with join and where clause. It selects every products or no product at all. Are there any method that more elegant than use multiple inner joins?

```sql
SELECT * FROM products
INNER JOIN attributes ON products.id = attributes.product_id
WHERE attributes.value IN ('Needed value #1', 'Needed value #2')
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM products
INNER JOIN attributes ON products.id = attributes.product_id
WHERE attributes.value = 'Needed value #1'
OR /* AND */ attributes.value = 'Needed value #2'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cat do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products
INNER JOIN attributes AS a1 ON
    products.id = a1.product_id AND a1.value = 'Needed value #1'
INNER JOIN attributes AS a2 ON
    products.id = a2.product_id AND a2.value = 'Needed value #2'
```

Comment: Yeah there was such option, but I thought there is more elegant way to do such query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by grouping by product_id the attributes table:

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT product_id FROM attributes
  WHERE value IN ('Needed value #1', 'Needed value #2')
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2
)
```

The condition `COUNT(DISTINCT value) = 2` in the HAVING clause makes sure that both attributes exist for this product.

Comment: I use more complicated stuff than in my example. Laravel query builder filters and scopes, and I don't really know how much there is attributes to filter on. And even if I know number of filters it seems like a hack.

Comment: You must include all the filters in the IN clause and the number of them in the HAVING clause.